# add Dynamic child views vertically to ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, viewgroup, android-viewgroup, android-constraintlayout

Android `ViewGroup` has the following methods to add (child) Views:

[image]

I know we can easily define horizontal/vertical orientation to LinearLayout in xml/programatically and add child views, eg.

[image]

Similarly with RelativeLayout, we can use `ViewGroup`'s `addView` and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`'s method:

[image]

I am also aware that we can use `LinearLayout` as a child inside `ConstraintLayout` and play with it.

Is there any solid and recommended way to add child views to ConstraintLayout dynamically?

**UPDATE**:
Let me give a not-so-simple example which I what I want to achieve.

Suppose you have a `View`1, `View`2 and `View`3. All V1, V2 and V3 are aligned vertically one below another and are complex views consisting of multiple `TextView`s and `ImageView`s. Based on user action and what server sends information, I need to add multiple V1 and V2 (can be 1 pair of V1-V2 and can be 3 pairs of V1-V2)between original V2 and V3. If I am using ConstraintLayout, would it be best if I add multiple constraints programatically when I can easily use LinearLayout with vertical orientation?

Now, in terms of efficiency, performance and less-and-beautiful-code, is ConstraintLayout best for this requirement as compared to Linear Layout?

Comment: You can use ContraintLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Why not add a LinearLayout within your ConstraintLayout, and add child views into it? Maybe put the LinearLayout inside a ScrollView if you want it to be scrollable.

Comment: @Nike15 please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589868/android-constraintlayout-how-to-add-a-dynamic-view-one-below-another/58407850#58407850). This answer might help.

Answer (score 9):

Views can be added to `ConstraintLayout` using `addView()` in the same way as you would with `LinearLayout`. The difference is that with `ConstraintLayout` the added views must be constrained. To constrain a view programmatically, use [`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet).

> This class allows you to define programmatically a set of constraints to be used with ConstraintLayout. It lets you create and save constraints, and apply them to an existing ConstraintLayout.

Here is a brief example:

**activity_main**
Define two `TextViews`. Center them horizontally and positioned at the top.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Top View"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Bottom View"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what you will see when a new `TextView` ("Middle View") is added to this layout without setting constraints. Notice that the new view defaults to position (0,0).

[image]

Let's say that we want the generated middle view to be placed between the top view and the bottom view centered horizontally in the window like this:

[image]

Here is the code that will produce this result:

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Define the new TextView and add it to the ConstraintLayout. Without constraints,
    // this view will be positioned at (0,0).
    TextView middleView = new TextView(this);
    middleView.setId(View.generateViewId());
    middleView.setText("Middle View");
    middleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20.0f);
    ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp =
        new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                          ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addView(middleView, lp);

    // Move the new view into place by applying constraints.
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    // Get existing constraints. This will be the base for modification.
    set.clone(layout);
    int topMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                                                    16, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    // Set up the connections for the new view. Constrain its top to the bottom of the top view.
    set.connect(middleView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.topView, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, topMargin);
    // Constrain the top of the bottom view to the bottom of the new view. This will replace
    // the constraint from the bottom view to the bottom of the top view.
    set.connect(R.id.bottomView, ConstraintSet.TOP, middleView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, topMargin);
    // Since views must be constrained vertically and horizontally, establish the horizontal
    // constaints such that the new view is centered.
    set.centerHorizontally(middleView.getId(),ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID);
    // Finally, apply our good work to the layout.
    set.applyTo(layout);
}
```

Comment: I did not specify my exact requirements earlier. Please read my updated question.